# Data Not Filtering in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: asp-classic, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've followed the examples http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

but instead of a fixed array I wanted a dynamic array from a database

I've almost got it working but as I type it won't filter the results and even if I type a letter that doesnt exist in the array, it still shows the full list.

[image]

**search.asp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: 'http://fullurl/autocomplete.asp'
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

**autocomplete.asp**

```
<%
sConn = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=SERVER; Port=3306; DATABASE=database; UID=username;PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3"     
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open sConn

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM makes ORDER BY makes ASC;"

Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.CursorLocation = 3
rst.Open sSQL, Conn, 3, 1

output = "["

DO Until rst.EOF
output = output & chr(34) & rst("makes") & chr(34) & ","
rst.movenext
Loop

output = left(output,(len(output)-1))
output = output & "]"

Response.Write output

rst.close
Conn.Close
%>
```

This is the result of autocomplete.asp: ["ACER","DELL","HP","LENOVO","SONY"]

any ideas what I've done wrong or missed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Jquery to the follow and works fine now

```
<script>
$(function() {
$.getJSON("autocomplete.asp", function(data) {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
  });
});
</script>
```